# How to speed up C++ compilation

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilation, qt5

do you have any tips to  really speed up a large C++ source code ?

I compiled QT5 with last visual studio 2013 compiler, this took at least 3 hours with intel quad core 3.2GHz, 8GB memory and SSD drive.

What solutions do I have if I want to do this  in 30 minutes  ?

thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure you can speed it up. This is because C++ depends on header files, which depend in their turn of other header files. Each files produces `.obj` file to be linked later. This procedure is *always* slow.

Comment: How often do you compile whole QT? => Is it really a problem to let it run overnight? And you probably won´t gain anything from 3 of your 4 cores. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx etc.

Comment: Did you check CPU usage in task manager to see if it was using all the cores effectively?  You might want to set the number of compilation threads to be a touch more than your number of physical cores.  You're probably not I/O bound though, so hyperthreading won't help.  Beyond that, modifying the QT project build tool and rules, and introducing techniques like pImpl and interfaces, explicit template instantiations, forward declaratoin headers so it compiles faster is presumably out of scope - that might take you 5 months.

Comment: @hughes Are you asking about compilation in general, compilation of libraries (immutable code),  compilation of applications (under dev) or about compilation of Qt specifically? How do you compile Qt? (there are several ways)

Comment: I find that some compilers compile more quickly than others (in particular, compiling under X-Code with g++ or clang++ compiles the same codebase for me much more quickly than compiling under Windows with MSVC).  Also don't forget to enable parallel compilation (e.g. make -j4 under Mac, or /MP under Windows)

Comment: @Drop It is for C++ compilation in general. Qt is a good example. Mostly I want to know the answer for my knowlage, this would help my improve my efficiency in C++ programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use a fast SSD setup. Or even create a ram disk, if suitable on your system.
- Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Multi-processor Compilation: Yes (/MP)
- Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run: and set the maximum number of parallel project builds. (already set to 8 on my system, probably determined on first run of VS2013)

Comment: 1-I did not enabled /MP...
2- I think there are also a lot of template and meta programming in the source code. For this there are nothing to do unless wait. Template using cost a lot...

Answer (score 5):

Forward declarations and PIMPL.

example.h:

```
// no include
class UsedByExample;

class Example
{
  // ...
  UsedByExample *ptr; // forward declaration is good enough
  UsedByExample &ref; // forward declaration is good enough
};
```

example.cpp:

```
#include "used_by_example.h"

// ...
UsedByExample object;  // need #include
```

A little known / underused fact is that forward declarations are also good enough for **function return values**:

```
class Example;
Example f(); // forward declaration is good enough
```

Only the code which calls `f()` and has to operate on the returned `Example` object actually needs the definition of `Example`.

The purpose of PIMPL, an idiom depending on forward declarations, is to hide private members completely from outside compilation units. This can thus also reduce compile time.

So, if you have this class:

example.h:

```
#include "other_class.h"
#include "yet_another_class.h"
#include "and_yet_another_class.h"

class Example
{
  // ...
  public:
    void f();
    void g();
  private:
    OtherClass a;
    YetAnotherClass b;
    AndYetAnotherClass c;
};
```

You can actually turn it into two classes, one being the implementation and the other the interface.

example.h:

```
// no more includes
class ExampleImpl; // forward declaration

class Example
{
  // ...
  public:
    void f();
    void g();
  private:
    ExampleImpl *impl;
};
```

example_impl.h:

```
#include "other_class.h"
#include "yet_another_class.h"
#include "and_yet_another_class.h"

class ExampleImpl
{
  // ...
    void f();
    void g();
  // ...
    OtherClass a;
    YetAnotherClass b;
    AndYetAnotherClass c;
};
```

Disadvantages may include higher complexity, memory-management issues and an added layer of indirection.

Comment: For more, see Herb Sutter's series on "compilation firewalls" and the Pimpl idiom: [part 1](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/19/gotw-7a-solution-minimizing-compile-time-dependencies-part-1/), [part 2](http://herbsutter.com/2013/12/31/gotw-7b-solution-minimizing-compile-time-dependencies-part-2/), and [part 3](http://herbsutter.com/2014/01/06/gotw-7c-solution-minimizing-compile-time-dependencies-part-3/).

Comment: My recommendation: do ***not*** forward declare library constructs in your client code; it can break your build if the library does some reasonable refactoring such as `class X;` (works for `int`s) --> `template <typename T> class basic_X { }; typedef basic_X<int> X;`.  Instead, ask the library author to provide a forward declaration header, which should be owned by the library and included by the library's own headers to ensure it stays consistent with the other library code.  Example from the Standard library: [the `<iosfwd>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd).

Comment: @Tony: can you elaborate on this? I'm afraid I don't understand your example at all.

Comment: Say you are writing an application that uses WunderLib v1.0, and you know the library header defines `class Lock_Free_Stack` that handles `int`s.  You forward declare `Lock_Free_Stack` in your own code.  Later, WunderLib v1.1 ships with the code improved to handle arbitrary types ala `template <typename T> class Lock_Free_Stack_of_T { ... }; typedef Lock_Free_Stack_of_T<int> Lock_Free_Stack`.  Wunder Girl - author of the library - was confident any old client code including her header and using `Lock_Free_Stack` would continue to compile and work, but yours will get a compile error instead.

Comment: The proper way to handle this is for Wunder Girl to provide a second header... wunderlib.fwd.h or similar... that would have had `class Lock_Free_Stack;` in v1.0, and been changed to have the template and typedef in v1.1.  Your code including wunderlib.fwd.h would then continue to compile after the library upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But I think there are three problems: 1.) The library author should not introduce any possible breaking change in the API in the first place, and this still *is* a breaking change. 2.) If you as the library client decide to upgrade the library, then you can change the forward declarations to includes, and the compiler will point to each and every place where this is necessary. Otherwise, you can choose not to upgrade to the new API. 3.) In v1.1 of your example, the header name ending with "fwd.h" would become misleading, as nothing would be forward-declared anymore.

Answer (score 1):

1. Cut down on the number of dependencies, so that if one part of the code changes, the rest doesn't have to be recompiled. I.e. any .cp/.cpp/.cc file that includes a particular header needs to be recompiled when that header is changed. So forward-declare stuff if you can.
2. Avoid compiling as much as possible. If there are modules you don't need, leave them out. If you have code that rarely changes, put it in a static library.
3. Don't use excessive amounts of templates. The compiler has to generate a new copy of each version of the template, and all code for a template goes in the header and needs to be re-read over and over again. That in itself is not a problem, but it is the opposite of forward-declaring, *and* adds dependencies.
4. If you have headers that every file uses, and which change rarely, see if you can put them in a precompiled header. A precompiled header is only compiled once and saved in a format specific to the compiler that is fast to read, and so for classes used a lot, can lead to great speed-ups.

Note that this only works with code you have written. For code from third parties, only #2 and #4 can help, but will not improve absolute compile times by much, only reduce the number of times code needs to be analyzed again after you've built it once.

To actually make things faster, your options are more limited. You already have an SSD, so you're probably not hard disk bound anymore, and swapping with an SSD should also be faster, so RAM is probably not the most pressing issue. So you are probably CPU-bound.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

1: you can make 1 (or a few) .cpp files that includes lots of cpp files from your project
Then, you compile only those files and ignore the rest.

> Advantages:

- compilation is a lot faster on one machiene
- there should already be tools to generate those files for you. In any case the technology is really simple , you could build a simple script to parse the project files and to compilation units, after that you only need to include those in the project and ignore the rest of the files

> Disadvantages:

- changing one cpp files will trigger the rebuild that includes that cpp file and for minor changes it takes while loger to compile
- you might need to change a bit of code to make it work , it might not work out of the box, for example if you have a function with the same name in two different cpp files you need to change that.

2: use a tool like [incredibuild](http://www.incredibuild.com/)

> Advantages:

- works out of the box for your project. Install the app and you can already compile your project
- compilation is really fast even for small changes

> Disadvantages:

- is not free
- you will need more computers to achieve a speadup

You might find alternatives for option 2 , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950514/xoreax-incredibuild-alternatives) is a related question.
Other tips to improve compilation time is to move as much of the code in cpp files and avoid inline declarations. Also extensive use of metaprogramming adds build time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply find your bottleneck, and improve that part of your PC. For example, HDD / SSD performance is often a bottleneck.

On the code side of things, use things like forward declaration to avoiding including headers where possible and thus improve compilation time further.

Comment: SSD performance is often a bottleneck? First time I hear of that. SSD is usually the biggest speed-up. As long as everything involved is on the SSD (i.e. code, OS, IDE and swap).

Comment: @uliwitness I don't have any daya  but if it is the biggest speedup, that makes it _more_ likely that it is the bottleneck, that's kind of how bottlenecks work

Comment: That makes no sense, is your sentence missing a "not" somewhere? Hard disks are slow, SSDs are much faster, near-RAM speeds.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use templates. Really. If every class you use is templated (and if everything is a class), you have only a single translation unit. Consequently, your build system is powerless to reduce compilation to only the few parts that actually need rebuilding.

If you have a large number of templated classes, but a fair amount of untemplated classes, the situation is not much better: Any templated class that is used in more than one compilation unit has to be compiled several times!

Of course, you don't want to throw out the small, usefull templated helper classes, but for all code you write, you should think twice before you make a template out of it. Especially, you should avoid using templates for complex classes that use five more different templated classes. Your code might actually get a lot more readable from it.

If you want to go radical, write in C. The only thing that compiles faster than that is assembler (thanks for reminding me of that @black).

Comment: Yup, there is: asm. Some will say C is a sort of wrapper, and it is true.

Comment: @cmaster: There are techniques to mitigate the negative impact of templates you describe here. The basic idea is to use a common, non-templated base class which operates on void* and use the template only as a kind of "type-safe wrapper" around the unsafe base class. See Item 42 in "Effective C++", 2nd edition ("use private inheritance judiciously").

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes, you can mitigate the effect *by thinking about what classes to make into a template*. That is my whole point. I'm not radically against any templates, but I'm radically against their overuse that's so often seen in modern C++. Not only for compiler performance reasons.

Comment: @cmaster: Yes, I think this is especially true for application code. In libraries, templates seem to make much more sense than in application-specific code. Of course, using templates for everything just because you can is like using OOP for everything.

Comment: Thanks, my point is files generated by template using is stored on drive instead of RAM, that is why there are a lot of time waist. Is it  true ?

Comment: @hughes No, I don't think that the object files are what's slowing you down. Compilation is generally bound by the amount of code that needs to be compiled / headers that need to be read, not by writing the result to disk. Output is one big, sequentially written file, input is tons of small files. I generally start twice as many compilation procs as I have CPU cores available, so that the CPUs have something to do while the other procs are waiting for the disk. Still, this can backfire if the memory gets exhausted and the system starts swapping (I had that once - with a C++ project...).

Comment: What you hear is neither the writing, nor the reading, it is the seeking. It is the sound generated by the read/write arm when it jumps into a new position to read/write something at a different location. You won't hear anything while a large file is written (just one small "clack" at the beginning), but you will hear it, when many small files are touched (one small "clack" for each file that is read/written).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what's been said previously, you should avoid things like:
 1. dynamic binding. The more it's complex, the more work the compiler will have to do.
 2. High levels of optimization: compiling for a certain architecture using optimized code (O`x`) takes longer.

Comment: I thought dynamic binding only happen in runtime

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers.

I have to enable multicores compilation and do some optimizations a little everywhere.

Most of the time cost is because of template.

thanks.